# Docker Swarm duplicates container after 'docker stack deploy'

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am running a docker swarm consisting of one manager node and one worker node. My application is running on the worker. For example a Wordpress Stack consisting of one wordpress service, one mysql service and one backup service. 
In the docker-compose.yml file I use a the following constraint to make sure wordpress only runs on the worker node.:

```
deploy:
  placement:
    constraints:
     - node.role == worker
```

To start the stack I run the command:

```
docker stack deploy -c ~/myapp/docker-compose.yml myapp
```

So far everything works as expected.

The Problem now is, when I change my configuration (in the docker-compose.yml file) I call the same command on my manager node to restart the stack:

```
docker stack deploy -c ~/myapp/docker-compose.yml myapp
```

The services are restarting correctly and I can see my changes. 
But now the old containers are still running. They snatch memory and cpu.

Why is this happen and why does docker swarm not stop the old containers after they are updated? I have to stop them manually.

Comment: What changes did you make to the docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: It's not necessary to change something. Only calling "stack deploy" results in the behavior.

Comment: Ok, I checked it again. It looks as if the problem is not reproducible. So I need to wait until it happens again and maybe I can give more information.

Answer (score 0):

To "stop" the stack, you need to `docker stack rm [stack-name]`:

```
docker stack rm myapp
#check the status on that bad boy before re-deploying:
docker stack ps myapp
```

I agree with your assumption that the stack should be restarted calling `docker stack deploy` against an already running stack - not sure if there is a particular reason why the stack does not re-deploy.

Comment: yes this sounds like the best way to handle updates in a stack. I will do a rm before I do re-deploy a stack.